# how to extract hex value from string by python?

Tags: python, regex

below is string
Register addr = [0x0128], data = [0x59]

i want to get 0x59 not 0x0128 by using Regex

this is my code

```
import re
data = "Register addr = [0x0128], data = [0x59]"
pattern = re.compile("d[.]]")
re.findall(pattern, data)
```

i don't have idea to get exact 0x59 could you help me?

Comment: is `0x59` the only string you wanna extract? or it may change?

Comment: is `0x59` always followed by word 'data' & '=' and within square brackerts?

Comment: only extract @Mox

Comment: @moys yes it is always followed that

Comment: Reverse the string, reverse the pattern, extract the first match. Or use `finditer`/`findall` with a appropriate pattern and keep the last. Maybe `r'(0x[^\]]+)'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
data = "Register addr = [0x0128], data = [0x59]"
print(re.findall(r'(?<=data\s=\s)\[(\w*)\]',data))
```

**Output**

```
['0x59']
```

you can also do `print(re.search(r'(?<=data\s=\s)\[(\w*)\]',data).group(1))`

**output**

Note that re.search returns ONLY the first match (it stops serching after the first match has been found.

```
0x59
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're only seeking to find `0x59` just do a direct search for it.

```
pattern = re.compile(r"0x59")
```

If you want to find all `hex` codes beginning with `0x` located within `[]`

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\[0x.*?\]")
re.findall(pattern, data)
#['[0x0128]', '[0x59]']
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do it is via:

```
print(re.sub(']', '', data.partition("data = [")[2]))
```

`.partition` splits the string on `data = [` giving a tuple & `[2]` selects the part of the string after `data = [`.

`re.sub` removes all of the `]` from that string.

Note, both 0x59 and 0x0128 are valid hex numbers.